# why google geocoding can't find some addresses

Tags: java, google-geocoding-api

hello I've got this java programe which gets the addresse from a database,make requeset to google geocoding api  and then I want to see the lat, lng cordinates.

Also as some addresses are not able to be found by google - so i've decided if google is unable to find the address with town and street, i make request only with the town name.

here is the java programe

```
public class TestCon {
    static String nodeString="";
    static String nody="";

    static String elementValue = "";
    static String townstr="";
    static String streetstr="";
    static String urlString;
    static Document geocoderResultDocument;

    static NodeList nodes2;
    static Connection conn2 = null;
    static NodeList nodes; 
    private static final String GEOCODE_REQUEST_PREFIX = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml";



    public String _xpath = null;
    public Document _xml = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,  URISyntaxException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
    {          Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        try 
        {
            conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/plovdivbizloca",
                    "postgres", "tan");
        }

        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

       for (int j=1500;j<1550;j++)

        {
           try 
        {
        conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/plovdivbizloca",
                    "postgres", "tan");
        }

        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        Statement mystmt = null;

        String selectQuery = "SELECT main_office_town, address FROM pl_biz where id="+j;

        try
        {
            mystmt = conn2.createStatement();
            ResultSet mysr = mystmt.executeQuery(selectQuery);

            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = mysr.getMetaData();
            int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

             elementValue="";
             townstr="";

            while (mysr.next()) 
            {

                for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) 
                {

                     elementValue += mysr.getString(i);
                    if (i < colCount)
                        elementValue += ",";
                }
                townstr = mysr.getString(1);
                streetstr = mysr.getString(2);
                //System.out.println(elementValue);
                //System.out.println(townstr);
                //System.out.println(streetstr);


            }

         }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
        }
        // NEW GEOCODING;

        String inputQuery, resultXml,  xPathString, xi = null;
        inputQuery = elementValue;

        urlString = GEOCODE_REQUEST_PREFIX + "?address=" + URLEncoder.encode(inputQuery, "UTF-8") + "&sensor=false";
        System.out.println("FIRST URL WITH THE WHOLE ADDRESS: "+urlString);

        // Convert the string to a URL so we can parse it
         URL url = new URL(urlString);

         geocoderResultDocument = makeConnection(url);


        // Process the results
        xPathString = "//GeocodeResponse//location/lat";
        nodes = process(geocoderResultDocument, xPathString);
        xi = "//GeocodeResponse//location/lng";
         nodes2 = process(geocoderResultDocument, xi);

        if ((nodes.getLength()==0)&&(nodes2.getLength()==0))
        {
            System.out.println ("ZERO RESULTS FOUND - making NEW REQUEST");
            urlString = GEOCODE_REQUEST_PREFIX + "?address=" + URLEncoder.encode(townstr, "UTF-8") + "&sensor=false";
            System.out.println("new url only with towwn" + urlString);
           //System.out.println(townstr);
            // Convert the string to a URL so we can parse it
            URL url2 = new URL(urlString);

             geocoderResultDocument = makeConnection(url2);
             System.out.println("EHOOO");
             nodes = process(geocoderResultDocument, xPathString);
             nodes2 = process(geocoderResultDocument, xi);
             System.out.println("after teh new search only with town  nodes length is: "+nodes.getLength());
        }


        if ((nodes.getLength()>=1)&&(nodes2.getLength()>=1))  
        {
            if ((nodes.getLength()>1)&&(nodes2.getLength()>1))  

                    {System.out.println("more than one result found - get the first closest");}


        // Print results
                        nodeString = nodes.item(0).getTextContent();

            System.out.println("lat_cordinate:"  + nodeString);



                   nody = nodes2.item(0).getTextContent();
                        System.out.println("longitude:" + nody);


        }
        else 
        {

            System.out.println("After making an request only with town - again zero result");
        }

        System.out.println("jjj"+j);


      }
    }



    public static NodeList process(Document xml, String xPathStrings)
            throws IOException {

        NodeList result = null;



        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();

        try {
            result = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(xPathStrings, xml,
                    XPathConstants.NODESET);
        }
        catch (XPathExpressionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

  public static  Document makeConnection(URL url) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException    
  { 
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    Document geocoderResultDocument = null;
    try 
    {
        // open the connection and get results as InputSource.
        conn.connect();
        InputSource geocoderResultInputSource = new InputSource(conn.getInputStream());

        // read result and parse into XML Document
        geocoderResultDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(geocoderResultInputSource);
    } 
    finally 
    {
        conn.disconnect();
    }

    return geocoderResultDocument;
  }
```

The problem is with the response I get:

I've tested the addresses and the cordinates and most of teh time thety are right and the response is right. But at some point i notice this weird situation- LOOK THIS RESPONSE FOR EXAMPLE FOR address with id=1512

---

FIRST URL WITH THE WHOLE ADDRESS: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%2C%D1%83%D0%BB.+%D0%94%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%AF%D0%9D%D0%9A%D0%90+2%D0%90+&sensor=false

ZERO RESULTS FOUND - making NEW REQUEST
new url only with towwn: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2&sensor=false

EHOOO
after the new search only with town nodes length is: 0

After making an request only withtown - again zero result

jjj1522

---

**if you click on the urls you will se that at both times the gooogle finds the address - but as you see the program gives me that google hasn't found the address - and i can't understand why**

Answer (score 0):

Try converting them to english addresses... Use the address is suggested in the results instead of the encoded russian address..